# Angular: seleccionar opción por defecto tras reset

Tags: angular

Tengo un filtro con varias opciones, y un botón de buscar y otro de reiniciar. Cuando entro en la página la opción por defecto que debe mostrar el filtro aparece. Pero si le doy al botón reiniciar se quita dicha opción por defecto y lo deja en blanco. He probado a ponerle "selected" a dicha opción pero tampoco funciona. ¿Alguna otra manera? Gracias

**html**

```
<select>
    <option value="">Todas</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Resetear" (click)="resetear()">
```

Comment: Podría por favor añadir lo que hace el método `resetear()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Según como trabajes puedes hacerlo de varias formas, en tu caso no veo que estés usando algún *id*, ni formulario aunque si veo un botón *submit* por lo que me hace dudar de eso jeje, pero te pondré algunos ejemplos sencillos de como puedes lograr la selección de un item:

Utilizando el decorador [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

HTML:

```
<select #mySelect>
    <option value="">Todas</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button (click)="resetear()">Resetear</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: ElementRef;

resetear() {
  this.cbxBorrar.nativeElement.value = ''; // Aquí igualas al value del ítem que quieras
}
```

---

Utilizando la directiva [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel):

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="opcion">
    <option value="">Todas</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button (click)="resetear()">Resetear</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
public opcion = '';

resetear() {
  this.opcion = ''; // Aquí igualas al value del ítem que quieras
}
```

---

Utilizando [formularios](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup):

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select formControlName="opcion">
        <option value="">Todas</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <button type="reset">Resetear</button>
</form>
```

TypeScript:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    opcion: new FormControl('')
  });
}
```